# how to hide rendering issues

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I'm using `constraintLayout` in new `android studio 2.2` and [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider). the project is running correctly with no issue but this rendering problem is very annoying, how can I hide or solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's clear, Your app is unable to find a `SliderStyle`.

Please take a look at the refrenced library,You are missing `SliderStyle`, you can find it in `attrs.xml` : 
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L82

Try adding the library again and do `Clean` and `Rebuild`

Comment: It's running so good and without any problem...you mean I have to add `attrs.xml` manualy to the project?

Comment: first of all clean rebuild, then change rendering API version and then try adding attrs. Also you must change your them in editor to fix the warning.